# solved, suddenly no more dual boot

Tags: release-hera, grub

I'm new to the subject an installed elementaryOS on a pretty old (1,8 GHz single processor) WinXP computer. So far everything worked fine for a few days.

Now when I try to boot Windows, I chose Windows in the grub list but it just flips back to elementary, which I can boot.

Tried supergrub2, it finds the Windows partiton, but also doesn't boot it.

Any ideas?

sven

PS: and suddenly I can't answer here any more, only editing works.
Well the problem is solved, I somehow destroyed the windows boot sector. Testdisk was able to fix the problem. Made a CD with gparted which included testdisk. And changed from elementary to linuxlite ...

Answer (score 0):

In your etc grub config, where is the default boot device pointing? What number selection is your default boot device? There is usually a number that tells grub to default if there is more than one boot device.

Did you also do sudo grub update after editing the configs? Happened to me where I updated mint, eOS and pointed to wrong name :P